# Procedurally generated riddles

Tags: riddle, pattern, reverse-puzzling

Last morning, my AI friend wrote me a letter.

> hello thomas. how are you? i am good. you said you like riddles so I made some riddles for you. please enjoy.

After some time, though I enjoyed the riddles, I still wasn't sure about my answers. So I asked my AI friend to send me a list of answers, so I could check with my own. He instantly answered with two letters.

> 1. A rooster
> 2. A person that can't see in the dark
> 3. A werewolf
> 4. A mutant who is also a good surgeon
> 5. A mutant
> 6. A circus bear that escaped back into the wild
>
> ...
>
> 13. A slightly better fighting machine
> 14. A good fighting machine
> 15. A fighting machine that gets upgrades for good performance
> 16. A veteran cat that is still at war
> 17. A veteran cat
> 18. A veteran cat with a bad memory
>
> ...
>
> 25. A reverse-werewolf
> 26. A cat that stumbled in the dark
> 27. A cat

As you can see, this letter didn't have all the answers. But I soon got another.

> sorry, i happened to have lost the answers to other puzzles. but i happened to save them in my cache. hope you enjoy.
>
> ? A bad fighting machine
>
> ? A bear pretending to be a human
>
> ? A cat at a hell of a war
>
> ? A cat at war
>
> ? A cat with a heat-sensitive paw
>
> ? A person who is too good at pretending to be a bear
>
> ? A self-repairing fighting machine
>
> ? An easily frightened inventor of a cloning machine
>
> ? An ever-evolving fighting machine
>
> ? An inventor of a cloning machine
>
> ? Puss in the boots

Having made my count, I answered him

> It seems like one answer is missing here?

To which he answered in his usual manner:

> yes

---

### The problem

Help me put the last 11 answers into proper order and answer the unanswered riddle!

**Hint:**

> Please google "fighting machine". I mean, it's a thing.

**Hint 2:**

> Inspect the breaking points: riddle 1, riddle 14 (middle), riddle 27. It's as simlpe as that. What's the difference between: a rooster, a good fighting machine, and a cat (in that order)?

**Hint 3:**

> If you're into riddles, I assure you you've already heard this one!

Comment: If we solve this, will you please reward us by sharing the 12 riddles your AI friend sent you?

Comment: @crcroberts I might have been unclear, but he sent me 27 riddles, not 12. And you will probably need to guess them so you could solve them so... nothing I can help you with.

Comment: On the second thought, there may be speculations about the numbers, corresponding to some of the answers. Not a lot though (similar to "Worth"/"Trade" misconception in my other riddle). So, if your answer is a little ambiguos you can still try.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting over after hint #3. This is based on the old riddle...

> What has four legs in the morning, two legs in the day, and three legs in the evening?

The catch is that since this is an AI generating riddles...

> It uses all possible number combinations.

Full list:

> 1. (2, 2, 2) A rooster
>  2. (2, 2, 3) A person that can't see in the dark
>  3. (2, 2, 4) A werewolf
>  4. (2, 3, 2) A mutant who is also a good surgeon
>  5. (2, 3, 3) A mutant
>  6. (2, 3, 4) A circus bear that escaped back into the wild
>  7. (2, 4, 2) **A person who is too good at pretending to be a bear**
>  8. (2, 4, 3) **An easily frightened inventor of a cloning machine**
>  9. (2, 4, 4) **An inventor of a cloning machine**
>  10. (3, 2, 2) **A bad fighting machine**
>  11. (3, 2, 3) **A self-repairing fighting machine**
>  12. (3, 2, 4) **An ever-evolving fighting machine**
>  13. (3, 3, 2) A slightly better fighting machine
>  14. (3, 3, 3) A good fighting machine
>  15. (3, 3, 4) A fighting machine that gets upgrades for good performance
>  16. (3, 4, 2) A veteran cat that is still at war
>  17. (3, 4, 3) A veteran cat
>  18. (3, 4, 4) A veteran cat with a bad memory
>  19. (4, 2, 2) **A bear pretending to be a human**
>  20. (4, 2, 3) **???**
>  21. (4, 2, 4) **Puss in the boots**
>  22. (4, 3, 2) **A cat at a hell of a war**
>  23. (4, 3, 3) **A cat at war**
>  24. (4, 3, 4) **A cat with a heat-sensitive paw**
>  25. (4, 4, 2) A reverse-werewolf
>  26. (4, 4, 3) A cat that stumbled in the dark
>  27. (4, 4, 4) A cat

The missing one is the original riddle, whose answer is...

> A man (four legs in infancy, two legs in adulthood, two legs plus a cane in old age).

Comment: I am very impressed so far. Some of the found patterns might be false, but still overall you're approaching the right idea. I'll add a slight hint soon, that, however, may even help you finish the solution.

Comment: For what it's worth, the way I organized the "answers" when I was staring at this (and coming to pretty much the same conjectures as jafe) was in a 3x3x3 cube, which I represented in my text editor as three 3x3 blocks. Not that this did me a great deal of good in terms of actually figuring everything out.

Comment: A cube does sound like a helpful visualization tool here. Hmmm...

Comment: Rewrote the whole thing into an actual answer.

Comment: Yeah, I believe there was an ambiguity that caused a mashup between 7/8 and 19/21 (you don't have to correct it, though, it's totally my fault). Apart from that, you are precise.

Answer (score 6):

Is it involved with

> the amount or the use of their legs or hands?

I noticed that some of them even

> gain or loss the use of their legs or hands.

For example:

A circus bear, puss in boots, or bear pretending to be a human

> Normally has four legs but can also stand on two legs.

A fighting machine that gets upgrades for good performance

> Normally has three legs but get upgraded to four.

A veteran cat that is still at war

> Normally has four but I guess the cat lost maybe one of his leg at the war?

And all that is left is to rate them in order accordingly.

Comment: You were right :)

Comment: Never get around to work more on it and put it together though. You really nailed it!