# Shouldn't it be "A bear pretending to be a human"?

Tags: riddle, rebus, knowledge

Inspired by [this amazing puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69012/procedurally-generated-riddles), [this rebus puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71407/looking-for-riley-rebus-3-its-right-here), and [this number puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/71581/make-0-0-0-0-8),
I create my first simple rebus:

> $(4, 2, 2) $

The answer is $4/(2+2)$ word
consists of $4+2+2$ letters

Hint 1

> You need to read carefully from where I got this puzzle

Hint 2

> You need to read carefully Thomas Blue's answer he almost gets the correct answer!

Hint 3

> The answer didn't need special [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) even it's not a common conversation word. It's quite popular I think, maybe I need to add [trivia](/questions/tagged/trivia).

Hint 4

> The answer is a living thing, but not really alive
>  The answer is a name, but not a real name

Comment: Wait, does this count as a rebus too? I never knew :D

Comment: as [the description](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/rebus/info) said the puzzle can be portrayed with a text, so I think it's fit :) and also to find the answer you need to use the "rebus-style" steps

Comment: Oh nice puzzle mate :D

Comment: your puzzle inspires this puzzle ;)

Comment: Really? Didn't know mine could ever be an inspiration :D

Comment: Like what @KevinL said, interesting puzzle! I have never seen a rebus like this before $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: is the title a hint?

Comment: @Shahriar Mahmud Sajid if you dont know why I use that title, then it is a hint :)

Comment: @malioboro it is time for hint 2.

Comment: @z100 for the first time I find it difficult to add another hint as Thomas Blue almost solve it. If I put a wrong hint, then this puzzle will be easily solved :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> Catwoman

Explanation

> 4 means "cat" who walks on four legs. 2 literally means "two" the first time. The second 2 means "man" who walks on two legs. Combine these together in a Riley fashion and you get Catwoman. (The t is used in both the prefix and infix)

Hint 1

> This puzzle was inspired by a puzzle which described creatures by how many legs they walk on.

Hint 2

> Thomas blue figured out that the numbers point to creatures from the inspirational puzzle. Kathmandu is kinda similar to Catwoman.

Hint 3

> Catwoman is common enough that you probably don't need the knowledge tag for this.

Hint 4

> Catwoman is a living thing but is not really alive because she is fictional. Catwoman is her name but no one is really named Catwoman.

Comment: yes, this is the correct answer! I've a question for you, does hint 4 make this puzzle easier? or you solve it without seeing hint 4?

Comment: I saw hint 4 but I don't think it helped a whole lot. For me the biggest hint was hint 2; just trying to figure out how Thomas Blue was close to the actual answer.

Comment: I see! thanks for the feedback, I'll try to make a btter puzzle next time :)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure I understand this one, but is it:

> Forty-two?

Because:

> When read out it sounds like 42 (Four-t'-two)

The answer is:

> $4/(2+2) = 1$ word. ([Numbers from 21-99 are hyphenated](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/hyphen-in-compound-numbers/) which somewhat makes them one word)

Consists of:

> $4+2+2 = 8$ letters. Forty-two has eight letters.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not an intended answer :) nice guess actually, but 2 in the middle I think it's not really fit with "ty", and the answer consists only of letters

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not the right answer, but I really wished it to be, so

> What if it's **Kathmandu**?

Although it doesn't fit with letters, it exploits logic of two puzzles (one is mine, btw):

> It can be split into Riley-form, as kath-man-du; The kath sounds like "cat" which was used as an example for 4-legged creature, the man is the example for 2-legged and du- means 2... probably latin or something. That gives us the (4,2,2). I don't know if I'm on any track at all, maybe somebody will find a good answer by using my stretchy logic ;D

Comment: Interesting concept but you exceeded the letter limit by just 1. :P

Comment: the number of letters is still not fit, so this answer is not the correct one. But, I'll say this is on the right track! +1 I hope you'll find the correct answer soon :)